# Finding strings in a file using regex and grep in Linux

Tags: regex, linux, grep

I am trying to find the proper regexes to use with the grep command on the file `text.txt`.

**Question**

1. Find all occurrences of words in text that have a substring ad, bd, cd, dd, ed.
2. Find all occurrences of numbers > 100
3. Find all occurrences of numbers > 100 that contain a digit 0 or 5

**My Approach**

1. `grep -io '[a-e]*d' text`

   Prints words with the proper substrings, but doesn’t print the whole string/word.

   ```
   ad
   d
   d
   ed
   d
   d
   ed
   d
   d
   d
   d
   ed
   d
   d
   ```
2. `grep -io '[199][1-9]*' text`

   I believe I am way off on the regex, but it still prints the correct result.

   ```
   1973
   197
   17775
   ```
3. `grep -io '[05][1-9]*' text`

   This is the continuation of 2., so I don’t understand the 2. part in 3., but I believe I have the string containing a digit 0 or 5 correct.

   ```
   0
   0
   0
   5
   ```

Comment: `-o` only prints the bit that matched so if you need more than the pattern you have you need to extend it to match the words/etc. you need.

Comment: Yes, that's my question to a) I know i have to add [a-zA-Z] somewhere but not sure in what position

Comment: Regexes are for finding text patterns, not for determining numeric values.  You'll want to use a tool like awk to evaluate numerics.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that Andy, I will review awk command soon

Comment: @AndyLester, you can match digit patterns with regular expressions, and thereby approach parts (b) and (c) with regular expressions.  Indeed, part (c) can probably be written more clearly and succinctly with regex than with arithmetic.

Comment: Hi John, did you remove your answer to the post? I was just looking at it and refreshed my browser and it was gone.

Comment: @darere I changed my mind about doing your homework for you.  I will revise it and bring it back in a more hint-like form.

Comment: Sounds cool, this exercise is actually from a math theory course so I won't really be practicing regexes much either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A) Find all occurrences of words in text that have a substring ad, bd, cd, dd, ed.

```
grep -ow '.*\(a\|b\|c\|d\|e\)d.*' text
```

or

```
egrep -ow '.*(a|b|c|d|e)d.*' text
```

B) Find all occurrences of numbers > 100

```
grep -ow '[1-9][0-9][0-9]\+' text
```

C) Find all occurrences of numbers > 100 that contain a digit 0 or 5

```
grep -ow '[1-9][0-9][0-9]\+' text | grep '\(0\|5\)'
```

or

```
grep -ow '[1-9][0-9][0-9]\+' text | egrep '(0|5)'
```

I'm using the option `-o` to output every match on it's own line and not the whole line where the pattern was found and the option `-w` that specifies that before and after the match should be a word boundary.

Comment: Hi hek, b) and c) work and are correct based on my understanding. But when using a) i think it is wrong because it prints a paragraph where some words don't match a)'s description

Comment: I'll let you know because I'm still going to review it in more detail for now I am going to take a break and come back later.

Comment: I would also like to break, probably until tomorrow. Its late here. But don't hesitate to ask, I'll answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

For part (a), the `-o` option to grep causes it to print *only* the part of the line that matches the pattern, but your pattern does not match whole words.  You simply need to adjust your pattern to match the parts of each word before and after the `[a-e]d` substring.

For part (b), your pattern is all wrong.  It will not match the numbers 299 or 1000, for instance.  The digit pattern you want is a digit between `1` and `9` followed by at least two digits between `0` and `9`.

Part (c) is the trickiest.  You must match digit patterns containing at least three digits, the first being between `1` and `9`, with either a `5` in the first position or a `0` or `5` in any other position.  You probably need to separate that into alternatives with the `|` operator.  It looks like you probably need three: the case where the lead digit is `5`; the case where the second digit is either `0` or `5`, and the case where some later digit is `0` or `5`.  In the third case you mustn't forget that there may be any number of additional digits, including zero, on either side of the `0` or `5` you match.

Comment: for a) would the regex be '[a-zA-Z][a-e]d[a-zA-Z]'?

Comment: for b) would the regex be '[1-9][0-9]{2,}' ?

Comment: @darere you're going in the right direction, but you're not there yet.  you need to match *any number* of letters on either side of the `[a-e]d`.  Also, although it's not wrong to include capital letters in your character classes, if you're using `grep -i` then you don't need them.

Comment: @darere, with respect to part (b), yes, that's just what I would do.  Note, though, that `grep` requires you to escape the `{` and `}` by preceding them with backslashes.

Comment: so b) is '[1-9][0-9]\{2,}\' ? and a) would be '[a-z][0-9][a-e]d[a-z][0-9]' ? Also for a) does it matter in which position [a-z] or [0-9] is placed such as [0-9] is first position instead?

Comment: @darere Almost. The `grep` command for (b) would be `grep -o '[1-9][0-9]\{2,\}'`.  As for (a), however, by "any number of letters" I did not mean that your words must contain digits, as your updated pattern would demand.  Consider what the `*` regex operator can do for you.

Comment: Ok then the correct answer would be "grep -io '[a-z]*[a-e]d[a-z]*' text" and based off my results in terminal it is correct thanks for the help.